# Deployed WCF Silverlight application returns 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, iis

I have a Silverlight 5 Web Application that I host in IIS 8. I can run my application fine in VS 2013 but on Deploying to a Windows 2012 server running IIS 8, my app fails to run. Fiddler gives me the following:
 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

My Web.config file is shown below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
      <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="......" />
  </appSettings>
  
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10000000" executionTimeout="120" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ABCD_ASPXAUTH" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName" />
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="AccessDenied.htm" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false" />
        <roleService enabled="true" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3765AD364E35" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AppServicesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ReportServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="userHttp">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" behaviorConfiguration="AppServicesBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="userHttp" bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200" />
      </service>
      <service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.RoleService" behaviorConfiguration="AppServicesBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.RoleService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="userHttp" bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200" />
      </service>
      <service name="Telerik.Reporting.Service.ReportService" behaviorConfiguration="ReportServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Telerik.Reporting.Service.IReportService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="resources" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" contract="Telerik.Reporting.Service.IResourceService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    ''''''''''''''''
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Critical, Error, Warning" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Projects\Log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Can someone tell me why a previously configured Win 2012 server does not now load the deployed application when I can still run from VS 2013? 
Or is there a way to get Fiddler to give a more detailed error?

I set Tracing on, but the log does not give any better clues.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your application pool in IIS is running. Is your application compiled as 32-bit application ? what version of .NET is setup for application pool in iis ?

Comment: Application Pool is running and the DefaultAppPool uses v4.0 Integrated. Not sure what bit my Application dll is compiled as.

Comment: Looking at your config file looks like you are using entity framework. assembly="System.Data.Entity.. Make sure the version of entity framework you are using in both your development environment and on IIS server is the same. That may be the cause for your error.

Comment: Thanks. My version of EntityFramework on dev environment is 5.0.0.0. How do i check/change the version on IIS Server?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have RIA Services installed on your development machine but it is not installed on the server.

You have two choices:

1. Remember to install RIA Services on each server you deploy to
2. Add the `RIAServices.Server` NuGet package to your *.Web project. This will add private local copies of the RIAServices dll to your solution.